# ¿Cómo volver a cargar componente de Angular al volver atras?

Tags: angular7

Tal vez no se entiende la pregunta, pero par dar más contexto de la situación:

Estoy en un proyecto angular en el que, estando en una ruta A y luego paso a la ruta B, al dar click hacia atrás con el navegador para volver a la ruta A, este ya no carga.

La pregunta es... ¿Cómo volver a cargar otra vez el componente que pertenece a la ruta A??

Noté que es un comportamiento normal de un proyecto angular, por lo que al parecer el código sería irrelevante...

Acotación:
Deseo ese comportamiento porque sucede que al volver atras, la página ya no muestra los datos obtenidos desde mi base de datos( lo que es tedioso porque necesitaría recargar la página siempre, por eso la pregunta...)

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar los estados con Ngrx https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store
Yo en algunos caso le paso los parámetros por querystring,. esto por ejemplo me permite abrir un link en una nueva ventana y sigue teniendo los datos